# Libgdx: Draw a Sprite on touchdown

Tags: libgdx, rendering

I want to draw A Sprite when touchDown event occurs and disposed when touchUp occurs. I tried following code:

```
public class Connect4Screen implements Screen {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Connect4Screen(){
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(30, 20);
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter(){

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            drawChip();
        }
    }
    }
    public void drawChip(){
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(new Texture("Images/yellow.png"), 0,  5, 1.4f,1.4f);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

I scrapped off unnecessary code.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply draw something as a one-time event, it will only be visible for 1/60 of a second. Games redraw the screen over and over in a loop, so to cause something to appear and stay on the screen, you need to set a member Boolean that indicates it should be drawn, and then in your render method you draw that item if the Boolean is true.

That's a very simplified explanation. Games tend to have many different items to draw that come and go, and keeping separate Booleans for each of them is impractical. So typically you'll have a list of items to draw, and you can add and remove items from the list based on events in the game. In your render method, you would loop through the list and draw everything in it.

Also, you must not create a `new Texture` without keeping a member reference to it so you can `dispose()` it later. Textures use native memory on the GPU and must be disposed of or they will leak memory. In LibGDX, any object that can leak memory implements `Disposable`, and must be disposed before you lose track of the reference.